# Filtering two MongoDB arrays not working (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express

I am asking MongoDB for two arrays of `objectIDs`, and then trying to compare the two arrays to find the difference.

I'm also passing the arrays through express middleware using `res.locals`.

Here is the code:

```
let questions = res.locals.questions;
let answers = res.locals.answers;
let outstanding = questions.filter(oid => !answers.includes(oid));

console.log("The outstanding oids: "+outstanding)
```

The result is always `blank`.

Maybe something to do with MongoDB's format, or the res.locals format? Appreciate any suggestions.

Here is what the two arrays look like:

```
questions: ["5f522bc55dd8993e58283526","5f522ab45dd8993e58283521","5f522ba65dd8993e58283525","5f522a5e5dd8993e5828351f","5f47a9a0b1764c3e285d4666"]

answers: ["5f522ab45dd8993e58283521","5f522bc55dd8993e58283526"]
```

Comment: are these strings or mongoDB objectIDs?

Comment: ore show us your mongoose model in case you use mongoose

Comment: When I perform typeof() test it returns "object". They are objectIDs in mongoose, so I assume they are objectIDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your values inside of the array are ObjectIDs and not strings so you cannot just compare them with like `==` operator.

Thankfully mongoose provides `.equals()` to compare object IDs.

```
let outstanding = questions.filter(oid => !answers.some(answer => oid.equals(answer)));
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense. Except, I want to return the ones that do not find a match, so needs to have `!answers.some`...etc

Comment: @IsraelPeck `answers.some` returns either true or false, then just invert it `!`